# If i click on first product_widget, how i can make disappear produst_name in first product_widget <div>?

Tags: javascript

If i click on first product_widget, how i can make click on produst_name  in first product_widget  ???

```
 <div class="product_widget">
    <div class="product_name"><a></a></div>
    <div class="product_image></div>
    <div class="product_price"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product_widget">
    <div class="product_name"><a></a></div>
    <div class="product_image"></div>
    <div class="product_price"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you have changed your question now ... now its even harder to understand what you want !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<div class="product_widget" onclick="doSomething(this)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function doSomething(elem) {
    var children = elem.getElementsByTagName("div");
    children[0].style.background = "blue";  
}
```

​This function basically gets the child `div` elements and updates the background color of the first `[0]` child. Obviously you can hide (`style.display = "none"`) or change its class as required.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atDgx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery

```
$('div.product_widget').click(function(){
 $('div.product_name').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$(".product_widget:first).click( function() {
    $(this).find(".product_name").hide();
});
```